# Animação para mover imagem para dentro de uma span

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma `div` com o `id="origem"` que contem uma imagem de uma estrela, como posso mover a imagem para a `span` com o `id="destino"` usando uma animação de por exemplo 2 segundos, o trajecto tem que ser em linha recta ou pode fazer uma curva? Também pode ser em loop como na imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
img {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div>fazer imagem ficar na direita desta frase: 
        <span id="destino"> 
                
        </span>
    </div>

    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    
    <div id="origem">------------------------------------------------------------------------
        <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148841.svg" alt="">
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Fortemente relacionada: [Como fazer animação com SVG ou CSS de um Texto andando pelo caminho?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/346357/5878)

Comment: Vik o snippet do stackoverflow só aceita imagem se a url for https ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara com o link citado pelo Anderson vc consegue sim algo bem mais sofisticado, mas só com CSS e alguns truques vc consegue algo semelhante, sem SVG, e mesmo assim, "curvando" a linha da animação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O detalhe é que enquanto a animação acontece vc vai diminuir o `width` do container ao mesmo tempo que muda a posição do background de `bottom` para `top`, e com isso vc vai criar uma curva.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A ideia é usar um *pseudo-elemento* no container, e não dois elementos "totalmente" separados como era sua ideia. Isso vai facilitar bastante a ideia da animação que agora é um simples `@keyframes`

Segue o código da animação

```css
.origem::after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 200px;
 width: 200px;
 background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/148/148841.svg);
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 background-position: bottom right;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

 animation: star 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes star {
 75%, 100% {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background-position: top right;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="origem">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
</div>
<div class="origem">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem, ipsum dolor.
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito a perceber como funciona as animações, o link para a sua outra pergunta/resposta também foi muito útil, vou dar uma estudada na outra solução, eu não queria que a animação repetisse mudei `infinite` para `forwards`, para já parece estar do meu agrado.

Comment: @vik legal que deu certo ai, a outra com SVG é um pouco mais complexa, mas tb é possível de ser feita. Mas esse modelo que deixei aqui acredito ser a melhor para o seu caso em particular... Sim o forwards para a animação no final, se vc quiser que a animação fique em linha reta basta remover o bg-position. []´s